# How can my application get to know about subscription expiry?

Tags: android, amazon-in-app-purchase

I have implemented amazon in-app in my android app, but I don't know what will happen when user's subscription will expire.

Right now, I am keep expiration details on my server hoping that after expiry, subscription will get available to the user.

How will my application get to know about subscription expiry?

Do I have to do anything?

Comment: to those who mark this negative, kindly let me know why that guy getting downgrade,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to ensure the subscription is valid is to make a call to getPurchaseUpdatesRequest() when the app starts. This way, you can examine the response and see if the user is still subscribed to the content. You just look for the most recent receipt for the parent SKU, and if the end date on the receipt is null, then the user is still subscribed.

Ref: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=188&tstart=30

Do we really need to maintain the user information of our own => No, you do not need to maintain any User information.

Ref: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=254&tstart=0

The current version of the SDK Tester allows for cancelled subscriptions, but not expired subscriptions.

Ref: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=221&tstart=30

You cannot test realtime scenario, You have to stick with SDKTester.